# Exclude wwwroot\dist from build asp.net dotnet core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I am trying to build asp.net dotnet core app vis CLI but I want to exclude `wwwroot\dist\**\*` from compilation.

In `dist` folder I have static file which need to be copied but not compiled. I tried by adding `ItemGroup` but cannot figure out.

Also I followed this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#files) but there is something which I don't understand and probably diong wrong.

Here si sample configuration:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Exclude="wwwroot\dist\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

One of my error is:

> error MSB4232: Items that are outside  Target elements must have one
>   of the following operations: Include, Update, or Remove.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <None Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But there could be something else in the game. Here is how "default" .net core 2 csproj should look like + "dist" folder ignore:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <None Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If you want to have content of folder copied to output and still visible inside VS:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It compiles, but what if I want to skip compilation only?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I am trying to skip compilation but copy in `publish` folder.

Comment: That is strange, when I put only `<Compile Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />` in ItemGroup it does not compile but copies data in publish folder.

Comment: I will investigate more but anyway your answer is helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can also ensure that the items are never added to the project so you don't have to remove them. This can be a bit more performant if the directory is ver large. To add excludes to the default glob pattern, you'd add this to your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);wwwroot\dist\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```